# Chat app. using express and socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a group chat app. When client login with his email and password, he would be directed to chat page with his name on top and he would able to chat with online user.How can my app.  identify from which user message was sent. One possibility is to send socket.id along with message to server  for identifying user but socket.id get changed on refreshing the page.

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/loginstyle.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <form  class="css" method="post" action="http://192.168.1.3:9373/valid" >
    <fieldset >
      <input type="text" name="email" class="inputemail"  placeholder="Email" />
    </fieldset> 
    <fieldset >
      <input type="password" name="pass" class="inputpassword" placeholder="Password" />
    </fieldset >
    <fieldset >
      <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.3:9373');

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

chat.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="name"> Welcome </div>
    <br></br>
    <div class="chat"></div>

    <form>
        <input type="text" class="msg"> </input>
        <button type="submit" class="enter">Send</button>
        <input type="file" class="file"></input>
    </form>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.3:9373');
    var online=[];
    var checkFile=0;

    $.get("/getName", function(string){
        username=string;
        $('.name').append(username);
    });

    $('.enter').bind("click",function(){

        $.get("/getMsg", function(){
            setTimeout (function(){
                socket.emit('chat message',$('.msg').val() );
                $('.msg').val('');
            },0);
        });       

        return false;
    });


        socket.on('chatmessage', function(name,msg){

            var block= $("<div class='message'> </div>");

            if(msg.length){
                var messenger= $("<div class='messenger'> </div>");

                messenger.append(name);
                block.append(messenger);
                var text;
                text=$("<div class='text'></div>");
                text.append(msg);
                block.append(text);
                block.append($("<div class='pad'></div>"));
                $('.chat').append(block);  
            }
        });    

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express')
, app = express()
, http = require('http')
, server = http.createServer(app)
, Twit = require('twit')
, io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
, os = require('os')
, open = require('open')
, bodyParser = require('body-parser')
, connect = require('connect')
, cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
, session = require('express-session')
, sessionStore = session.MemoryStore()
, async = require('async')
, mysql = require("mysql");

var id=[];
var a;

server.listen(9373,'192.168.1.3');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(cookieParser("secret"));

app.use(session({
   store: sessionStore,
   secret: "54321",
   saveUninitialized: true,
   resave: true
}));

app.get('/loginme', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/loginmysql.html');
});

app.get('/option', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/option.html');
});

app.get('/getName', function (req, res) {
  var r = {};
  r.name = req.session.userid;
  res.send(r.name);
});


app.get('/getMsg', function (req, res) {
  a = req.session.id;
  res.json(a);
});

app.get('/chat', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});


app.post('/valid', function (req, res) {

  var username=req.body.email;
  var password=req.body.pass;

  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    "hostname": "localhost",
    "user": "root",
    "password": "vk123",
    "database": "login"
  });

  connection.connect();

  connection.query('SELECT * FROM id WHERE email=? AND password=?', [username,password], function(err, rows){

    if (err){
      throw err;
    }else{

      var name=rows[0].name;
      req.session.userid =  name;
      id.push({sid:req.session.id, username:req.session.userid});
      res.redirect('http://192.168.1.3:9373/option'); 
      io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){
        io.emit('name',name);
      });     
    }
  });

  connection.end();

});



  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){


    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      var user;
      var i;
      for(i=id.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        if(id[i].sid == a){
          user=id[i].username;
          break;
        }
      }
      io.emit('chatmessage',id[i].username,msg);      
    });

  });

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
```

Comment: Could you please add your code?

Comment: Couldn't you get the user's login information from your webpage/database?

Comment: I can but client can manipulate his name that is sent to server

Comment: Just have it get validated server-side so it only works if the validation returns true.